# Are lockless ring-buffers technically possible?

Tags: thread-safety, circular-buffer

I need to implement a lockless ring-buffer but I still haven't found any way of doing it without a kind of lock. I've searched the internet and all I found are ways using bits to say the memory is locked.

So, it is technically possible to do it without a lock?

Comment: So, have you read this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ring-buffer-design.txt ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is it uses bit flags to basically say "you can't read here, it's locked for now"

Comment: Oh, I must have been inattentive. You've mentioned it in the question.